# php - sort by value of last key in array?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how to sort an array by the value of the last key, when the number of keys are unknown?

So, if I have arrays that look like this:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
      [0] => Bob 
      [1] => A 
      [2] => Parker
  )
  [1] => Array(
      [0] => John 
      [1] => Smith-Doe
  )
  [2] => Array(
      [0] => Giuseppe 
      [1] => Gonzalez
      [2] => Octavio
      [3] => Hernandez
  )
)
```

I want to sort it by the last value in the array:

- Giuseppe Gonzalez Octavio Hernandez
- Bob A. Parker
- John Smith-Doe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    array('Bob', 'A', 'Parker'),
    array('John', 'Smith-Doe'),
    array('Giuseppe', 'Gonzalez', 'Octavio', 'Hernandez')
);

usort($arr, 'sort_by_last_item');

var_dump($arr);

function sort_by_last_item($a, $b)
{
    return end($a) > end($b);
}
```

or if you're using php 5.3:

```
$arr = array(
    array('Bob', 'A', 'Parker'),
    array('John', 'Smith-Doe'),
    array('Giuseppe', 'Gonzalez', 'Octavio', 'Hernandez')
);

usort($arr, function($a, $b) { return end($a) > end($b); });

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: +1 for good answer (and if I could a second time for the lambda)

Answer (score 1):

```
$data  = array( /* your data */ );
$output = array();

foreach ( $data as $v ) {
    $output[ end($v) ] = $v;
}

ksort($output);

var_dump($output);
```

alternatively:

```
$data  = array( /* your data */ );
$output = array();

foreach ( $data as $v ) {
    $key = implode(' ', array_reverse($v));
    $output[ $key ] = $v;
}

ksort($output);

var_dump($output);
```

Second method allow you to have many records with the same last element and sorts by last elements, and if they are equals - sort by first before last and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function array_last_item_sort($array){
    $return = array();
    $sort = array();

    foreach($array as $i => $item){
        $sort[$i] = $item[count($item) - 1];
    }

    asort($sort);

    foreach($sort as $i => $value){
        $return[] = $array[$i];
    }

    return $return;
}
```